# Как завершить подключение к TelegramClient в Google Colab

Tags: python

Нужно, что бы отработало один раз, сейчас постоянно работает. Как исправить?

```
async def main():
    async with TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
       massage = 'Один' #сообщение для канала
       await client.send_message('me', massage)  
       print ("Отправил") 
       await client.run_until_disconnected()
       
await main()
asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался:
лишний код asyncio.run(main())
Для разового прохода достаточно удалить await client.run_until_disconnected()

В итоге получаем код:

```
async def main():
    async with TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
       massage = 'Один' #сообщение для канала
       await client.send_message('me', massage)  
       print ("Отправил") 
       
await main()
```